# What is the hidden achievement in Little Alchemy?

Tags: achievements, little-alchemy

This new web game, Little Alchemy, has a hidden achievement. Does anyone know how to get this achievement?

> **Is This Just Fantasy?**
>   A hidden gem, eh?

[image: gem]

https://littlealchemy.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wikia page](http://littlealchemygame.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_gems), you get this achievement for crafting one of the nine hidden gems.

> There are 9 hidden gems in Little Alchemy. Creating one will get you the achievement "Is This Just Fantasy?"

The gems you can craft to get this achievement are:

- Astronaut Ice Cream (astronaut + ice cream)
- The Doctor (tardis + doctor)
- Tardis (space + time)
- Doge (dog + computer)
- Keyboard Cat (cat + music)
- Ninja Turtle (ninja + turtle)
- The One Ring (ring + volcano)
- Yeti (mountain + story OR mountain range + story)
- Nessie (story + lake)

<sub>(Combinations gotten from the wikia in conjunction with [this site](https://littlealchemyguide.com/hidden-gem/), as the wikia did not have Nessie)</sub>